# Parse bytes to str while reading csv with Python

Tags: python, csv, utf-8, encode

While I python code that write and read to csv file utf8 string

```
import csv

test1='ab"cc"dd'.encode('utf8')
test2='bbb'.encode('utf8')
csv_file = open('test.csv','w')
writer= csv.writer(csv_file)
writer.writerow([test1,test2])
csv_file.close()

with open('test.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    print(spamreader)
    for row in spamreader:
        print(', '.join(row))
```

The problem is that when I  read I got `b'ab"cc"dd', b'bbb'` instead of `ab"cc"dd,bbb`

How can I decode that string (I must put utf8 into csv) ?

Comment: Why you are passing list of bytes into `writerow`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for manual encoding/decoding.  Open the file with the specific encoding you want because the default encoding varies by OS configuration.  This is called the "Unicode sandwich".  Encode/decode when writing/reading the file and work with Unicode only within the Python script.

Also, `csv.reader` and `csv.writer` expect Unicode strings, so providing encoded byte strings is incorrect.

```py
import csv

test1 = 'ab"cc"dd'
test2 = 'bbb'
with open('test.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as csv_file:
    writer= csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerow([test1,test2])

with open('test.csv', encoding='utf8', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in spamreader:
        print(row)
        print(', '.join(row))
```

```
['ab"cc"dd', 'bbb']
ab"cc"dd, bbb
```

Additionally, if you want your .CSV files to be readable in Microsoft Excel, use `utf-8-sig` as the encoding or it won't detect UTF-8 properly.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the decode() function to decode bytes to string.
More info on that here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode

```
"b'ab""cc""dd'", b'bbb'".decode('utf-8')
```

If it doesn't work correctly, decode the strings(presented in bytes) before joining them.

Comment: Probably want to decode before joining `print(', '.join([x.decode() for x in row]))`

Comment: @MoPo @C14L I got error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Comment: Do as C14L comment, decode them before joining them. join() forms a string, and you can't decode a string. So you need to decode them then join them @MicrosoctCprog